# awk sum of different files result saved in different files

Tags: awk

To make it more simple could this command create a file in each directory with the sum of the `*traffic*` files.

command:

```
find /config -maxdepth 2 -name "*traffic*" -exec awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i } END {print sum > "xx.txt"}' {} +
```

I have no clue how to make `awk` save a file for each user, because I don't have only `/config/mark/` I also have `config/john` and `/config/mary` and so on, and no idea how I could save the file in that directory.

So expected output would be a `xx.txt` file in each folder with only the current folder sum of `*traffic*` files so `/config/mark/`  should have sum of all `*traffic*` files exported into `xx.txt`, also `/config/john` should have the same thing but only with the sum from `/config/john` folder.

sample input is `00002 0000000000 0000051327 #test` in one file and I have more files similar to this file in a directory like `/config/mike/traffic1.txt` , and `/config/mike/traffic2.txt` with another value `00002 0000000000 0000331327 #test` and the output should be just the sum of the files

I have managed to make this from what I was able to find, but it's adding files one by one and I need it to add all the files in working directory and make the sum.

```
find /config -name '*traffic*' -printf "$PWD:%p\n" | while IFS=":" read FPATH FNAME
do
        echo "FNAME = $FNAME"
        echo "FPATH = $FPATH"
        echo ""
        awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i } END {print sum >> "'$FNAME'xxxx"}' "$FNAME"
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention sample input and sample of expected output in your post and do let us know then.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include sample input and output. Thanks for the welcome and for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to find a solution myself , seems the $PWD didn't worked so instead I used %h so final code, let's say we have a folder config with *traffic* files in some subfolders from /config and you want to add the numbers in traffic files to a file called result.txt

Here is the code:

```
 find /config -name '*traffic*' -printf "%h:%p\n" | while IFS=":" read FPATH FNAME
do
    awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i } END {print sum >> "'$FPATH/'result.txt"}' $FNAME
done
```

It will create a result.txt in each folder it finds a *traffic* file

Comment: There's no reason to complicate things by putting the output redirection inside the awk script, just leave it outside with the rest of the shell stuff: `...END {print sum}' "$FNAME" >> "$FPATH/result.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE, gensub(), and multi-char RS (untested):

```
find /config -name '*traffic*' -exec \
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{sum+=$0} ENDFILE{print sum+0 >> gensub("[^/]+$","xx.txt",1,FILENAME); sum=0}' {} +
```

or:

```
find /config -type d -maxdepth 2 |
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{sum+=$0} ENDFILE{print sum+0; sum=0}' "$dir"/*traffic* > "$dir"/xx.txt
done
```